# How to get community or site name in an LWC component in connectedcallback?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, customer-community, js

I have one requirement where I want to get the Community name as soon I open it well it can have in any component which is in the DOM of that community page.

I can get the page name but how I will get the community or site name as well?

Comment: check this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_community_info, you should be able to dig out the site name from the url

Answer (score 3):

You can get the basePath from the Summer '20 module to get the community name: (source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules)

```
// Syntax
import basePathName from '@salesforce/community/basePath';
// Example
import communityPath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';
```